# background image issue after parsing 2 html files

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image

I am currently haven issues displaying the background img of my site. the problem is probably in my css but caused by the layout of my html.

In order to show a navbar on each page without duplicated code, i simply let my controller parse a navbar file and a content file.

the navbar.html has a layout of

```
<html>
    <body>
        //navbar code
    </body>
</html>
```

while the content file have a layout of

```
<html>
    <head>
        //head code
    </head>
    <body>
        //body code
    </body>
</html>
```

i parse this from the controller using

```
$this->parser->parse('navbar', $data);
$this->parser->parse('content', $data);
```

which leads to a final source code of

```
<html>
    <body>
            //navbar code
    </body>
</html>
<html>
    <head>
        //head code
    </head>
    <body>
        //body code
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i got the image responsive on all pages without header with this css

```
html, body{
    //make body fill entire page
    width: 100%;
    //height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background:
        /* top, transparent black, faked with gradient */ 
        linear-gradient(
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
        ),
        /* bottom, image */
        url("http://webapps.groept.be/a15_web01/img/wallpaper.jpg");



    /*make sure background image is responsive*/
    background-position: center center;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The pages where i load both the navbar and content now put the body at height:100% which ofcourse means that the content overlaps the navbar.
Is there a way to adjust the css for this? or does anyone know a better layout for the navbar issue?

Comment: an HTML page can have only one html element

Comment: well the strange thing is that it works, it's just not fully responsive...
any idea of a better way to construct the html?

Comment: how do you put these two html files together into one file/page?

Comment: why don't u try bootstrap??

Comment: I don't want to put it into 1 page because i am trying to avoid duplicated code. I have multiple tabs, and don't want to put the navbar code in each one, also put in how i parse it: `$this->parser->parse`

Comment: Well for starters you definitely need to remove the `<html>` and `<body>` tags from your navbar.html file. I would think it only needs navbar html in it and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found it, i'll quickly list the useful answers as an overview.

1. Removed `<html>` and `body` tags from navbar file
2. changed css to only work on the html tag
3. added css: `body{ background-color: transparent; }`

anyway, thanks for the help guys